# Flutter What is plugin_platform_interface and how to remove it from app?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

So I have an app that cannot be archived in xcode because of plugin_platform interface does not support null safety. The thing is I don't use that and that package cannot be found inside pubspec.yaml. I searched for it inside my files and it appears to be inside image_picker library pubsec.yaml. And when I saw the version, it is version 2.0.0 which should support null safety. So what is the problem now? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which version of image_picker do you use?

Comment: image_picker_ ^0.8.6

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your cache and update dependencies

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`